# Timestamp Field is always returned as {} when connected to mysql through jaggery

Tags: mysql, sql, wso2, mysql-connector, jaggery-js

Below is the code used

```
config={};
var dataSource = new Database("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","root",config);
result=dataSource.query("select * from testtable");
print(result);
```

The response i received is

```
[{  
  "count":3,
  "site":"Site 2",
  "bank":"Bank 2",
  "size":"SMALL",
  "transactionDate":{  

  }
},
{  
  "count":2,
  "site":"Test Site",
  "bank":"Test Bank",
  "size":"SMALL",
  "transactionDate":{  

  }
},
{  
  "count":15,
  "site":"Site 2",
  "bank":"Bank 2",
  "size":"",
  "transactionDate":{  

  }
}]
```

Notice the transactionDate field [ DataType timestamp]. It is always returned as {} but the field has data for each record in the table.
The data for transactionDate looks like :
2014-07-03 00:00:00
2014-07-04 00:00:00
2014-07-05 00:00:00

Answer (score -1):

You could change your SQL to have all fields from testtable and use for timestamp:

```
..,CAST(timestamp AS CHAR) AS timestamp,..
```

Or you create a view where timestamp is converted already to avoid listing all fields in your code.